# Using java library from android framework in packages/apps

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I am adding an app as part of my android build. The app make use of android-support-v4.jar. So I put the jar file inside libs folder of my application and make a reference to it from the Android.mk file of the application as shown.

```
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libs/android-support-v4.jar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

On compiling the source code, I get the following error:

```
build/core/base_rules.mk:170: *** packages/apps/Personalization:  MODULE.TARGET.JAVA_LIBRARIES.android-support-v4 already defined by frameworks/support/v4.   Stop.
DDK build start.

error: build_android



build/core/base_rules.mk:170: *** packages/apps/Personalization:  MODULE.TARGET.JAVA_LIBRARIES.android-support-v4 already defined by frameworks/support/v4.   Stop.
DDK build start.

error: build_android
```

Can someone please let me know what need to be done such that, I can get rid of this error and get my build to work ok

**UPDATE**

My complete Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    android-support-v4 \
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := Personalization
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libs/android-support-v4.jar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
        android-support-v4
```

This should work. Put it anywhere before `include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)`

Comment: Please see my updated Android.mk file. With this mk file , I get the following build error: `build/core/package.mk:43: *** packages/apps/Personalization: Package modules must define LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME.  Stop.
DDK build start. `

Comment: Delete the final \ after android-support-v4

Comment: I removed the final \ . Now it gives the same error which I posted in the question: `build/core/base_rules.mk:170: *** packages/apps/Personalization:  MODULE.TARGET.JAVA_LIBRARIES.android-support-v4 already defined by frameworks/support/v4.   Stop.
DDK build start.`

Comment: Definitely, remove your added line. LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libs/android-support-v4.jar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)